# VCOS does not name a type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi, raspbian, visualgdb

I'm, trying to output video from raspicam to framebuffer 0, and I'm having an issue with BCM_HOST, where I get a ton of errors from the included vcos.h.
All the errors are of the same 2 types:

```
'VCHPRE_' does not name a type,
'vcos_boot_t' has not been declared,
```

In files: connection.h vc_ispmanx.h, message.h etc.

etc. 
I'll link to a full pastebin of errors below

I don't even know where to begin solving these, I moved /opt/vc from raspbian to my sysroot folder using VisualGDB's synchronize sysroot feature, and all the include files are there.

Is this a problem with the files themselves? It can't be,

Thanks for any help,
-D

Pastebin link: https://mypastebin.com/xQdN7mZZInHx

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#include "bcm_host.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
{
    DISPMANX_DISPLAY_HANDLE_T display;
    DISPMANX_MODEINFO_T display_info;
    DISPMANX_RESOURCE_HANDLE_T screen_resource;
    VC_IMAGE_TRANSFORM_T transform;
    uint32_t image_prt;
    VC_RECT_T rect1;
    int ret;
    int fbfd = 0;
    char *fbp = 0;

    struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
    struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with [mcve]. Please avoid links to code stored in external sites.

Comment: added a simple example that generates these errors

Comment: What errors? Please copy-paste any, and all, compilation errors, into the question itself, without paraphrasing.

Comment: 2 of the errors shown above, pastebin link with 300+ lines most errors are the same. `does not name a type` and `has not been declared` are the only error types i get

Comment: Are you including whatever header defines `VCHPRE_`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that using VisualGDB sysroot synchronize tool causes some files to be copied with 0 length. I checked vcos.h and it was empty, but on my linux system it had data. Fixed by copying all the files manually.